# ¿Es posible inicializar un array de x longitud asignando valores en C++?

Tags: c++, array

Quisiera saber si es posible inicializar un array asignando valores. ¿La única manera es iterando con un `for`?

Algo que es muy fácil en *Javascript* es declarar una variable asignando valores, y además tiene la ventaja de que no es necesario indicar la longitud del array, en comparación con *C++*.

```cpp
var array=[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Si yo hago pongo el `5` dentro de los corchetes en *C++*, no tengo ningún problema, compila y todo:

```
int array_enteros[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
```

Pero cuando yo hago lo siguiente:

```
int 5;
int array_enteros[digitos]={1,2,3,4,5};
```

El *CodeBlocks* me tira error:

> Warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
>
> error: assigning to an array from an initializer list
>
> error: variable-sized object 'array_enteros' may not be initialized

Lo que quisiera hacer es declarar un array pero indicando la longitud mediante una variable, o de ser posible, sería mucho mejor no necesitar el uso de la variable, y que cambie la longitud automáticamente dependiendo de la cantidad de valores que yo le asigne.

Comment: @Trauma No, fue un error al redactar la pregunta... Fueron varios en realidad, como el de poner 5 cuando son 6 del 0 al 5.

Comment: Ok. No me fijé tanto.

Comment: Tema [relacionado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/13960/existe-alguna-forma-para-que-en-un-array-todas-las-variables-tengan-el-mismo/13999#13999).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es que el array tenga la longitud igual al número de valores que tiene el array, sin tener que declarárselo puedes dejar los corchetes `[]` vacíos y C++ asumirá automáticamente el tamaño del array con los valores que tú le has indicado.

Ejemplo:

```
int array_enteros[]={0,1,2,3,4,5};
```

Desde la [documentación](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/):

> When an initialization of values is provided for an array, C++ allows the possibility of leaving the square brackets empty `[]`. In this case, the compiler will assume automatically a size for the array that matches the number of values included between the braces `{}`:
>
> `int foo [] = { 16, 2, 77, 40, 12071 };`

En español sería:

> Cuando se proporciona la inicialización de valores al array, C++ permite dejar los corchetes vacíos `[]`. En ese caso, el compilador asume automáticamente el tamaño del array, que coincide con la cantidad de valores incluidos entre llaves `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

Como cuando creás un `for` necesitás declarar la variable primero e inicializarla:

```
for(int i=0;i<=5;i++)
```

Podés declarar una variable:

```
int mi_variable=5
```

... y el array:

```
int mi_array[mi_variable]
```

El array toma el valor de `mi_variable` que es 5.

Comment: Sí, ahora entiendo, hasta ahí está todo bien, el problema es cuando yo quería asignar los 5 valores... Pero igual ya me respondieron correctamente.

Comment: Los VLA **no están permitidos** en C++ estándar. `int mi_array[mi_variable]` **no** es correcto. Si te funciona, es por una extensión de tu compilador, pero es *ilegal*.

Comment: ok que bueno que ya te respondieron, suerte..